# Connection speed between blades

Tags: networking, hp, blade-server, bladecenter, blade-chassis

a local company sponsored our university a bladecenter (HP c7000) equipped with 16 HP c460 blades. Our main issue is, that we don't know at which network speed the blades talk to each other.

**Our goal is:**

- building a private cloud with opennebula on 15 blades
- use the 16th blade as storage (maybe we buy a hp 2200sb storage blade)

**Our network setup is:**

- Gigabit Ethernet ports at the back of the blade system
- the local network controllers in the blades should be capable to use 10 gigabit ethernet?

To plan further, we want to at which speed do the blades communicate to each other over TCP/IP? E.g.: Blade 1 to Blade 3 file transfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the server generation.

The downplane connections of G6 and newer blades have the capability of 2 x 10GbE LOMs per server.

[image]

While your backplane connections sound like they're 1GbE, the blades should be able to communicate at 10GbE between other blades housed within the same chassis.